# Does the c++ sort() function in <algorithm> fail for large inputs of size (number of elements) >10^7 elements of an integer array?

Tags: c++, function, sorting

The following code produces a run time error for inputs of size(number of elements) > 10^7 elements. The elements are read from a text file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    long long int n;
    cin>>n;
    long long int a[n];
    for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    sort(a,a+n);
    for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact runtime error it produces? Is it stack overflow? What?

Comment: Debugging stack overflow issues on stackoverflow.com ... :)

Comment: I'm running the program from the command prompt and it just says sort.exe has stopped working. I tried using a try catch block  to determine the type of error but in vain as: try
    {
    //block of code
    }
    catch(exception& e)
    {
        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: It surprises me whenever people start blaming libraries without any concrete reason. Running std::shuffle on the array would probably cause the same problem, and that should be a hint that the problem is in the intersection of the two programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long long int a[n];
```

This makes use of a GCC extension called [variable length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). These are allocated on the stack. The stack is merely a few MiBs large, so you get an overflow.

Use `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. Standard C++ does not support variable size arrays `cin n; long long int a[n];`
2. You probably run out of stack memory (10^7) elements.

Best thing to do is to use a `std::vector<long long int>` instead,

```
std::vector<long long int> a(n); // rest of the code will be unchanged
```